# How can I scrobble the output of SongRec?

Tags: sound, microphone, music, last.fm-client

Using Ubuntu that I runs as my desktop I want to be able to automatically scrobble my record/CD playing on my stereo to [last.fm](https://www.last.fm/).

[SongRec](https://github.com/marin-m/SongRec) does a great job of recognising and reporting on the songs by listening in through a microphone so the source doesn't matter. It gathers all the required information.

I can export a CSV from the GUI of SongRec and I can import it into last.fm.

*How can I make the whole thing happen automatically? ie I play a vinyl record and it is scrobbled to last.fm with no manual steps.*

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu? please [edit] accordingly

Comment: What is the word "scrobble"?